# How can I share a Time Capsule connection?

Tags: time-capsule, sharing

I have my Time Capsule connected via wi-fi, and I want to share that connection with my other 2 computers via their ethernet. So basically, share the current wifi connection that my Time Capsule has and make sure that my other 2 computers can connect to the internet via that Time Capsule's ethernet ports. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Since the Time Capsule is an Airport Extreme with an internal hard drive it's relatively easy to convert it into a wireless to wired bridge assuming you already have it set to hook up to the wireless network.

1. Open up Airport Utility and start Manual Setup on your Time Capsule
2. Go to the Internet section
3. Under Internet Connection be sure Connection Sharing is set to Bridge Mode

If bridge mode is turned on it will share the connection and essentially act like a switch.